# Get a char predicate `Char => Boolean` from a Regex Character Class?

Tags: regex, scala, performance, predicate

Is it possible to obtain a `Char => Boolean` function from a Regex character class without compiling the pattern every time?

This does type-check, but it recompiles the pattern every time, which is inefficient:

```
val f: Char => Boolean = c => c.toString.matches("[bgjkqtz]")
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
// compiles a regular expression `rgx` into a predicate on characters.
def toPred(rgx: String): Char => Boolean = {
  val p = rgx.r.pattern
  c => p.matcher(c.toString).matches
}
```

It compiles the pattern `p` once, and then stores it in the closure. Examples:

```
scala> val f = toPred("[abcdef]")
scala> f('a')
res5: Boolean = true

scala> f('x')
res6: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use pattern matching.

```
val myChars = "[bgjkqtz]".r  //compiled once

def predicate(c :Char) :Boolean = c match {
  case myChars() => true
  case _ => false
}
```

But I don't know how performant it would be since this would also involve the underlying calls to `unapplySeq()` and `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `"[fkadjd]".replaceAll("[\[\]]").toSet`?

`Set[Char]` *is* a `Char => Boolean`, you don't really need a regex to match a character ...

Comment: For `[\\d]` or just `\\d`, it's going to be annoying. For more complex character classes like `\\p{L}`, it's going to occupy lot of space, be vastly inefficient, and actually quite difficult to emulate by an explicitly enumerated set (how would you enumerate all emojis with that? I don't know...).

Comment: Probably not the answer OP is looking for, but for a handful of single chars this is a fun solution.

Answer (score 0):

The specific example you give does not need a regular expression because it just checks that `c` is in a set of characters. It can be done with `contains`:

```
val f: Char => Boolean = c => "bgjkqtz".contains(c)
```

Comment: Actually, that example was added to the question in an edit by @AndreyTyukin (copied from my example code). See also his comment to @Dima. A more realistic example might be something like `[\w-[aeiou]]`.

Comment: @jwvh I think both you and Dima used it as example, so I decided to add it to the question. On `"bgjkqtz".contains`: first, you could have omitted `c =>` and `(c)`, second, this is `O(n)` in number of characters... That definitely doesn't scale well to `[^a]` etc.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I agree that this is not a general solution and does not scale. But your suggestion of omitting `c =>` and `(c)` is incorrect: `contains` on `String` takes `CharSequence` so you have to force the implicit conversion to `SeqLike` to get the version that takes `Char`.

Comment: @Tim Oh, you're right. Here is another alternative which makes use of the underscore syntax: `val f: Char => Boolean = "abcdef".contains(_: Char)` (this time, it compiles, at least in >2.16)

Comment: That's actually quite an interesting example: `val f: Char => Boolean = "abcdef".contains[Char]` also fails to compile, even though there is only one method that takes type parameters. Interesting corner case.